# What words frequently collocate with "-wise"?

Tags: vocabulary, suffixes

Would it make any sense if just combined any nouns with with *-wise*? For example, *Aesthetic-wise*? *Money-wise*?

Comment: The 1960 Billy Wilder comedy "The Apartment" had the following tagline: Movie-wise, there has never been anything like "The Apartment" - laugh-wise, love-wise, or otherwise-wise!

Comment: Would have made for a good question if only backed by some homework.

Comment: The title of your question asks something quite different from what you ask in the body of your question, and is far too broad. I recommend you [edit] the title to change it to something like "Are there any nouns that can't take -wise as a suffix?" which is still asking roughly the same thing but with a much narrower scope. Off-hand, I can only think of one noun where it wouldn't make much sense: *wisdom*. But even then, it would in principle be an acceptable usage.

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: [What does the idiom "That's the way it crumbles, cookie-wise" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/306240/what-does-the-idiom-thats-the-way-it-crumbles-cookie-wise-mean) (Note that this expression appears in _The Apartment_, the movie that Tushar Raj cites in a comment above.)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, yes.

However, mind the usage note on [ODOL](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/-wise):

> In modern English the suffix -wise is attached to nouns to form a sentence adverb meaning ‘concerning or with respect to’, as in confidence-wise, tax-wise, price-wise, time-wise, news-wise, and culture-wise. The suffix is very productive and widely used in modern English **but most of the words so formed are considered inelegant or not good English style** (emphasis mine).

A more exhaustive study of the phenomenon of "wising nouns," Houghton says in his article *[The Suffix -Wise](https://www.jstor.org/stable/454465?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)* in "American Speech":

> The use of the suffix *-wise* … is a fairly recent development in English, …. True, its status is still uncertain — there are many who detest it stylewise — but its wide dissemination through the mass media and its increasingly frequent appearance in the speech and writing of Americans … suggest that it may well become firmly established in Standard English, at least in this country.
>   …
>   Thoreau uses *manna-wise* in *Walden*, Melville *harpoonwise* in *Moby Dick*, …

So, we'd better wait for now, and see how it turns out in 2019.

**One note**, though. Be careful with the other suffix *wise*, as in *streetwise* (street-smart). I always felt uneasy about using *-wise* in *money-wise* in the sense of "as for" rather than "sensible about".

Btw, today *wise* is not much of a "word" so we could talk about collocation. Rather, as correctly mentioned, *-wise* (not *wise*) is now essentially a suffix.

Comment: 1) good answer 2) but why would you vote to close if you would then answer? It's like you're trying to prevent anyone else from answering.

Comment: @Mitch & anr. To encourage and guide the NC, Doh!

Comment: The 'NC'? Anyway, you should unvote your close vote or at least vote to reopen since you consider this question answerable if you haven't already.